# How to make a fragment shader replace white with alpha, opengl-es

Tags: opengl-es, fragment-shader

I am trying to come up with a opengl-es fragment shader that will replace the white pixels with alpha. The image with the checkered background is what I want. The checkered background represents the image after alpha conversion. Any tips? Normally I'd hate asking this here but I can't find anything on it.

[image: Before fragment shader]

[image: After fragment shader]

Comment: Bitmap texture maybe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Getting the "white pixels" as in the image you posted seems to be getting a grayscale component. That is summing up RGB values dividing by 3. Then output RGB are all .0 in your case and the alpha equals to the grayscale pixel...

```
    vec4 textureSample = texture2D(uniformTexture, textureCoordinate);
    lowp float grayscaleComponent = textureSample.x*(1.0/3.0) + textureSample.y*(1.0/3.0) + textureSample.z*(1.0/3.0);
    gl_FragColor =  lowp vec4(.0, .0, .0, grayscaleComponent);
```

Answer (score 1):

Properly speaking, grayscale value is 0.2126 * R + 0.7152 * G + 0.0722 * B
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grayscale

Comment: That is unfortunately very debatable. Although this approach is most likely best when dealing with live taken photos it might not be appropriate for most computer generated images. Simply imagine you would try to make a grayscale image of image which uses only a blue color component using the equation you posted. The result would be quite dark, the lightest pixel would be converted to about 7.2%... Such colors are not natural and are not common on photos though.